# How to sync countdown timer, same link in two separate tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, countdowntimer

I would like to know if there's a way to sync react countdown timer two different tabs, like below:

1:46                 ||          1:52 
first tab        ||          second tab

Thanks

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I imagine you would need to agree on a system time common to both tabs at which the countdown expires.  What is the obstacle you encountered that brought you to Stack Overflow?  What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Wyck, i created a timer from reactjs, the time came from the backend (300sec), then display it on the front. it displays well in the front, the problem is, if i open another tab (same link), it was not sync. other tab was delayed like 5secs to the other.

Comment: @Julietta You can store the target date as UTC string on the server and have the client show the difference between `Date.now()` and the time from the server. All clients (and definitely all tabs on a single client) should show more or less the same countdown value unless their local time settings are way off.

Comment: @HMR, will explore on this one.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Countdown timers, Generally Speaking

Typically a countdown timer is defined by choosing a *due time* at which the timer will reach zero.  A relative countdown timer would define that *due time* using a calculation based on the current time.  In other words, to set a timer for "10 seconds from now" where *now* is defined to be the moment at which the user clicks a *start* button, one would use code like this:

```
// In the start button's click handler
due = Date.now() + 120000 // 120000 is 2 minutes (120 s) expressed in milliseconds
```

This gets evaluated when you click the button.  If you click the button again, the due time would be recomputed and the due time would be moved to be a moment 10 seconds into the future from the moment at which you clicked the button.  In other words, the program will evaluate `Date.now()` again, and choose a new due time based on that.

Now to compute, at a given instant how much time is remaining, you can use the following computation:

```
remaining = due - Date.now()
// `remaining` contains number of milliseconds remaining until our countdown is due
```

This will be a positive number in the moments before the timer is due, and will be negative if evaluated after the moment the timer is due.  And, if you happen to be really lucky, you might catch it at the exact moment it is due and `remaining` would be exactly zero.

Typically a countdown timer will periodically *update* (change the value it is displaying) at least once a second, although possibly with greater frequency (could show tenths of a second remaining, or even milliseconds) or possibly with lower frequency (you could choose to update the display only once per minute).

To update the display you would use a JavaScript *interval timer* in the client.  The frequency of this timer just governs how often you want to update the display and has nothing to do with its due-time or the precision with which you display the remaining time (i.e. whether you show "2 min remaining" or "2:00 remaining" or "2:00.000" remaining)  For a nice, precise display you could update 60 times per second (about the refresh rate of a typical display) or if you're only displaying to a precision of seconds, updating 10 times per second is likely often enough, depending on the application.

Example:

```
setInterval(() => {
  display(`${due - Date.now()} ms remaining`);
}, updateInterval);
```

`display` could be just `console.log`, or code to change the text of a DOM element, or it could be a React `setState`.  Depends on your application.  `updateInterval` might be 250 to update at a modest 4 times per second.

> True story:  I keep a paper wall calendar, but I don't flip the monthly page at exactly midnight.  Sometimes I don't flip it until the 2nd or 3rd day of the month, actually, but I generally "poll" once every two or three days to see if it needs to be updated.  I don't set an alarm to wake me up at midnight just to change my calendar.  Generally checking once a day is good enough for me.  A countdown timer works the same way.

#### Sync

To have two countdown timers that are intended to be synchronized, they must both be based on the *same due time*.  And should both be updating frequently enough that you won't notice any discrepancies due to the display just being stale.

If you have two browser tabs on the same computer that should be synchronized, then it's sufficient to just tell the apps in both tabs the same due time.  Each tab has access to the same system time via `Date.now()`.  So each will be able to display how much time remains until the due time by computing `due - Date.now()`.

As for your React countdown timer, I'm sure there's a way to set the due time as a JavaScript Date.  Just make sure that the server sends the same due time to both tabs and it won't matter when each tab loads and starts the countdown timer because the client won't be assigning the value of the due date for the local display of the countdown timer based on `Date.now()`, it will receive the due time explicitly from the server.

The point is that it's up to the server to provide the due time for the timer.  Two countdown timers that are destined to reach 0 at the same time are effectively the same logical.  The displays will appear reasonably synchronized if they are kept up to date at a reasonable frequency.

Be careful to transmit the date to the client using UTC so there are no issues due to time-zone differences between server and client.

---

If you need help programming your React countdown timer to set it for a specific due date, then you should disclose which library/component you are using and show code for how you set the timer.